# Can we share an application window among different users/X servers?

Tags: linux, x11, wayland, xvfb, x11vnc

We have a family machine with KDE, where each member has a different account. Mom, dad and children.

There are a few applications we'd like to be shared in such a way that they be available to all users at the same time, whilst running as a single instance.

- The application window should show on each user's X (or Wayland?) server, as if they had opened it themselves.
- The application could be kind of run/be owned by a group, rather than an individual user, or a shared user, in case, so that shared data remains indeed shared.
- The application's window should be available for users to attach to whilst running, as if it was a remote-desktop app, or the like.
- Ideally we'd like to have some sort of native integration, something more similar to "ssh -Y some-host command", than a video streaming solution like vnc.

I know there is xvfb, but once the output of an app is sent to that server, it can't be redirected to another one, :0, :1, :2, can it?

I wonder if any such thing as above can be accomplished with existing tools somehow?

Comment: note ssh `-Y` flag is dangerous. And `-X` should be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: You can do it with VNC, if you set up one app per VNC server (I am not sure about resizing).

Comment: yeah, I'd like to avoid VNC, as it sounds like a performance hit for the task...

Comment: VNC may be a performance hit. Depends on what you are doing (it will block direct rendering etc), and a small amount of translation. For most programs it will not matter.

Comment: Does it matter that there is a single instance of the program? would it be OK to share config. Can you add a little about the use case. It will help us come up with solutions. (the problem is to abstract at this time, for me to help).

Comment: Use case: I run an app under my account. I lock up, then another user logs in under theirs, but I want them to be able to see the same running app in their environment, as if they had started it.

Since the X server has a kind of list of windows belonging to it, there might be some way to transport an existing window under a different X server? E.G.: from :0 to :1...

Comment: Is it on a different monitor, or is it just another window?

Comment: it's just another window

Comment: Which applications (this may make a difference to the answer: performance, or other app specific solution)? Do you have to share the exact same view, or is sharing the configuration enough?

Comment: the idea is to share the same view. e.g. same browser, music player app, mail client. It's not like 3d games or so.

But this makes me curious about other answers, as well. What can be done by just sharing configuration, as you say?

Comment: Config is in files, so they are easily shared. Also please edit the question to put all updates into it. So that people can find all information needed to answer it, in one place.